# Google Sheets Formula cannot get the date from another cell

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, array-formulas

I want to get the price of bitcoin on exact date.

The dates are written in `Column A` and they are updated regularly from a Google form

This is an example of the working formula, but the date in it is written manually (2017-01-31):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK($B$2:$B),"",CRYPTOFINANCE("BTC/USD", "price",2017-01-31)))
```

But when I try to get the dates from `Column A`, mentioned with `$C$2:$C` - Google sheets do not understand it

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK($B$2:$B),"",CRYPTOFINANCE("BTC/USD", "price",$C$2:$C)))
```

[Click here to check The spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12VlflvvMgUdAyjyCtwPbjCpgHpcrTb7_Ah209SW4s7w/edit?usp=sharing)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: CRYPTOFINANCE isn't a built-in function. Are you using an add-on?

Answer (score 0):

*"Doctor, it hurts when I do this."*

In the example spreadsheet you are converting the dates into text for the column C, using the explicit TEXT() function. Then you are wondering why they no longer work as dates?

Stop converting to text.

Comment: I tried also using Column A, the result is the same

Comment: Well, I don't know then - I've played a bit with your spreadsheet and it looks to me that the CRYPTOFINANCE function is broken, or at least not made to be used inside ARRAYFORMULA.